# How do I update since flatbutton is deprecated

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

```css
height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height \* 0.1 \* buttonHeight,

color: buttonColor,

**child: FlatButton(**

shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(

borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(0.0),

side: BorderSide(

color: Colors.black12,

width: 1,

style: BorderStyle.solid)),

padding: EdgeInsets.all(16.0),

onPressed: () =\> buttonPressed(buttonText),

child: Text(
buttonText,

style: TextStyle(
fontSize: 30.0,

fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,

color: Colors.black
),
)
),
```

Im trying to update from flatbutton to textbutton, but it lead to other error

Comment: what error? ...

Comment: please mention the errors

Answer (score 0):

In TextButton, all your style should be inside the "style: ButtonStyle"  like this:

```
TextButton(
style: ButtonStyle(
  shape: MaterialStateProperty.all(
    RoundedRectangleBorder(
      side: const BorderSide(
        color: Colors.black12,
        width: 2,
        style: BorderStyle.solid,
      ),
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(0.0),
    ),
  ),
),
child: Text(
  "CLICK ME!",
  style: const TextStyle(
    fontSize: 30.0,
    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
    color: Colors.black,
  ),
),
onPressed: () {
  debugPrint("Click Button pressed");
},
),
```

[Screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PLP0G.png)

Comment: I did it like this and it works! (PART 1)

height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.1 * buttonHeight,
      color: buttonColor,
      child: TextButton(
        style: TextButton.styleFrom( 
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(16),
          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(0),
            side: BorderSide(
              color: Colors.black12,
                  width: 1,
                  style: BorderStyle.solid
            ),),
          ),

Comment: PART 2

          onPressed: () => buttonPressed(buttonText),
          child: Text(
            buttonText,
            style: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 30.0,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                color: Colors.black
            ),
          )
      ),

Answer (score 0):

**After Flutter update some of Widgets are Deprecated.**

You Used `TextButton` instead of `FlatButton`, **FlatButton** is *deprecated by flutter*.

Refer Documentation [here](https://docs.flutter.dev/release/breaking-changes/buttons) for changing the buttons

**Your Code:**

```
 TextButton(
        style: TextButton.styleFrom(
          side: BorderSide(
            color: Colors.black38,
          ),
        ),
        onPressed: () {
          //write onPressed function here
          print('Button Pressed');
        },
        child: Text('Pressed Me'),
      ),
```

Your result screen-> [image]

Answer (score 0):

**IT WORKS! I DID IT like this**

height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.1 * buttonHeight,

```
  color: buttonColor,
  child: TextButton(
    style: TextButton.styleFrom( 
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(16),
      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(0),
        side: BorderSide(
          color: Colors.black12,
              width: 1,
              style: BorderStyle.solid
        ),
    ),
      ),
      onPressed: () => buttonPressed(buttonText),
      child: Text(
        buttonText,
        style: TextStyle(
            fontSize: 30.0,
            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
            color: Colors.black
        ),
      )
  ),
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).